# Tricky MongoDB search challenge

Tags: mongodb, search, meteor

I have a tricky `mongoDB` problem that I have never encountered.

**The Documents:**

The `documents` in my `collection` have a search `object` containing named `keys` and array `values`. The keys are named after one of eight `categorys` and the corresponding value is an `array` containing `items` from that category.

```
{
  _id: "bRtjhGNQ3eNqTiKWa",
  /* */
  search :{
    usage: ["accounting"],
    test: ["knowledgetest", "feedback"]
  }, 
  test: {
    type:"list",
    vals: [
     {name:'knowledgetest', showName: 'Wissenstest'}, 
     {name:'feedback', showName: '360 Feedback'},   
    ]
  },
  usage: {
    type:"list",
    vals: [
     {name:'accounting', showName: 'Accounting'},    
    ]
  }
},
{
  _id: "7bgvegeKZNXkKzuXs",
  /* */
  search :{
    usage: ["recruiting"],
    test: ["intelligence", "feedback"]
  }, 
  test: {
    type:"list",
    vals: [
     {name:'intelligence', showName: 'Intelligenztest'}, 
     {name:'feedback', showName: '360 Feedback'},   
    ]
  }, 
  usage: {
    type:"list",
    vals: [
     {name:'recruiting', showName: 'Recruiting'},    
    ]
  }
},
```

**The Query**

The `query` is an `object` containing the same  `category - keys` and `array - values`.

```
{
  usage: ["accounting", "assessment"],
  test : ["feedback"]
}
```

**The desired outcome**

- If the query is empty, I want `all` documents.
- If the query has `one` category and any number of items, I want all the `documents` that have all of the `items` in the specified `category`.
- If the query has more then one category, I want all the `documents` that have all of the `items` in all of the specified `categorys`.

**My tries**

I tried all kinds of variations of:

```
XX.find({
'search': {
  "$elemMatch": {
    'tool': {
      "$in" : ['feedback']
    }
  }
}
```

No success.
**EDIT**
Tried: `'search.test': {$all:  (query.test ? query.test : [])}` which gives me no results if I have nothing selected; the right `documents` when I am only looking inside the `test` category; and nothing when I additionally look inside the `usage` category.

This is at the heart of my app, thus I historically put up a [bounty](https://bountify.co/mongodb-complex-query-design-2).

Comment: When searching for all array elements given in a query, you'll have to use $all, not $elemMatch. Nevertheless, this does not solve your problem, which basically is, that the data structure you store is not suited to the query you want to make. You should rather use the categories as keys to store the arrays individually. Then each individual query comes down to { 'category' : { $all : [ myinputarray ] }}. Note that this is a document database - modeling is to be done by the QUERIES you expect, not by whatever model you imagine best.

Comment: @mtj each document also contains the categories as keys, but there the data is nested into `showName: "string", type:{}, vals:[ {name:"string", showName:"string"}], [{…}]` with the relevant entry beeing `vals[x].name`.

Comment: @mtj I edited the **Documents** part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let tools = []
    const search = {}
    for (var q in query) {
      if (query.hasOwnProperty(q)) {
        if (query[q]) {
          search['search.'+q] = {$all: query[q] }
        }
      }
    }


    if (Object.keys(query).length > 0) {
      tools = ToolsCollection.find(search).fetch()
    } else {
      tools = ToolsCollection.find({}).fetch()
    }
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

What I already hinted at in the comment: your document structure does not support efficient and simple searching. I can only guess the reason, but I suspect that you stick to some relational ideas like "schemas" or "normalization" which just don't make sense for a document database.

Without digging deeper into the problem of modeling, I could imagine something like this for your case:

```
{
  _id: "bRtjhGNQ3eNqTiKWa",
  /* */
  search :{
    usage: ["accounting"],
    test: ["knowledgetest", "feedback"]
  }, 
  test: {
    "knowledgetest" : {
       "showName": "Wissenstest"
    },
    "feedback" : {
         "showName": "360 Feedback"
    }
  },
  usage: {
    "accounting" : {
        "values" : [ "knowledgetest", "feedback" ],
        "showName" : "Accounting"
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: "7bgvegeKZNXkKzuXs",
  /* */
  search : {
    usage: ["recruiting"],
    test: ["intelligence", "feedback"]
  }, 
  test: {
    "intelligence" : {
        showName: 'Intelligenztest'
     },
     "feedback" : {
        showName: '360 Feedback'
    }
  }, 
  usage: {
    "recruiting" : {
        "values" : [ "intelligence", "feedback" ],
        "showName" : "Recruiting"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, a search for "knowledgetest" and "feedback" in "accounting" would be a simple

```
{ "usage.accounting.values" : { $all : [ "knowledgetest", "feedback"] } }
```

which can easily be used multiple times in an and condition:

```
{
  { "usage.accounting.values" : { $all : [ "knowledgetest", "feedback"] } },
  { "usage.anothercategory.values" : { $all [ "knowledgetest", "assessment" ] } }
}
```

Even the zero-times-case matches your search requirements, because an and-filter with none of these criteria yields {} which is the find-everything filter expression.

Once more, to make it absolutely clear: when using mongo, forget *everything* you know as "best practice" from the relational world. What you need to consider is: what are your queries, and how can my document model support these queries in an ideal way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to implement that. it might take some time, but if it works, i already put up a [bounty](https://bountify.co/mongodb-complex-query-design-2) :) 

I have close to no experience in query design, so all the additional help you can give is welcome. thats the reason for the bounty!

Comment: Basically it is quite simple: design your application and ask yourself: what do I need to query from the database in one go at which place. Then, write your documents so that these queries get as simple and efficient as they can be. Do not fear redundancy, do not fear denormalization. Unless you store real big things in documents, the maximum doc size of 16MB is plenty and disk storage costs close to nothing nowadays. (Take the last sentence with a grain of salt, of course ;-))

Comment: I was able to use the datastructure I already had. Just posted an answer